# mysql efficient select query for each user (use join or not)

Tags: mysql

I have the following job select query (the actual query is massive with many joins)
Main query:

```
SELECT id FROM job LIMIT 20
```

When the user log in, I want to select if the user has saved the job. (many users but one main result)

My question is more efficient method? (thinking in terms of query cache, buffer pool etc)
method 1:

```
SELECT id, Member 
FROM job AS t1 LEFT JOIN Member AS t2 ON (t1.id=t2.Job) LIMIT 20
```

(i.e. if user didn't saved the job it would return 'Null' for Select Member)

method 2:
use the Main query for the main result, then for each result select (i.e. loop sql query)

```
 SELECT Member FROM Member WHERE Member=1 AND Job=(each job id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it's more efficient to bundle into a single query to reduce round-trips to the DB, query parsing cost, etc. However, if bundling into a single query means returning a bunch of data you don't need, then it may not be more efficient than individual queries.

Answer (score 0):

The method with the left join is almost guaranteed to be more efficient.

While the underlying logic is essentially the same (ie: you're comparing to the same column against the same value) and while the LEFT JOIN query will be more expensive to parse, when using LEFT JOIN, you're only doing 1 round-trip to the server while with the looped query you're doing multiple round trips to achieve the same result.

Generally speaking, it's difficult to give generalized answers to such questions since much of it depends on your specific setup and data, but in this case you should see the single LEFT JOIN query being significantly faster.

I've benchmarked such queries in the past in the LEFT JOIN approach was always faster.